# Maintain change log (audit trail) of the whole database in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: logging, sql-server-2012

I have a database with lots of tables. Now I want to maintain a log which will contain changes made in the table.

After some research, I came up across an approach where we can maintain a shadow table and then apply a trigger on each table. But the problem is I have many tables and maintaining all tables copy and assigning them triggers would take lot of time.

Is there any approach with which I can maintain all change logs of all table at only one place, that is, one table?

Comment: Read what the [Change Data Capture feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx) has to offer.

Comment: Yes.  I read about that but it doesn't seem to add values like,  'who changed it? '.